# BeforeUpdate event validation control

Tags: excel, vba, validation, controls, beforeupdate

Dears,

I want to make a simple userform to record some serial numbers into excel, it contains a textbox_serialNo., a command button “enter” and another command button “cancel”.

I made a validation control in that serialNo textbox so that only number can be entered.  However, when I run the program and input some numbers into the textbox, both command buttons (the "enter" button named as label_enter,the "cancel" button named as label_cancel) have no reactions (e.g. the "cancel" button doesn't unload the form when press) , how should I correct the program?  Below are the relevant codes, Thanks.

```
Private Sub TextBox_SerialNo_BeforeUpdate(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If Not IsNumeric(TextBox_SerialNo.Value) Then
    TextBox_SerialNo.BackColor = rgbYellow
End If
Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox_SerialNo_AfterUpdate()
If TextBox_SerialNo.Value <> "" Then
    TextBox_SerialNo.BackColor = rgbWhite
End If
End Sub

Private sub label_enter_click()
sheet1.Select
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox_SerialNo.Value
 TextBox_SerialNo.Value = ""
 End Sub

Private Sub Label_Cancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are "both command buttons" pieces of code? How to answer your question referring to these two buttons without, at least, seeing their code? Are you really referring to command buttons?

Comment: Hi, "both command buttons" means the "cancel" command buttons and the "enter" command buttons. The "cancel" command button codes are already shown in above, for the "enter" command button codes, it is: sheet1.select; Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select; ActiveCell.Value = TextBox_SerialNo.Value; ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1; ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = TextBox_SerialNo.Value; TextBox_SerialNo.Value = ""; end sub

Comment: 1. Please, do not post code in a comment. Edit your question and place the code there. 2. Then, do you have a button named as "Label_Cancel" and it does not unload the form when pressed? 3. Any selection, from what I could understand in the posted code, is useless. You should avoid selecting, activate...

Comment: Hi, i have just updated my codes in the question, and yes, i have a button named as "Label_Cancel" and it doesn't unload the form when pressed.  There may have many mistakes in my codes.....

Comment: Your code looks not optimized, but it should work. Can you share the workbook you are using?

Comment: When i run the program, after i enter some number into the textbox, both the "enter" button and "cancel" button shows no change when i press them...sorry, i think it is not convinent to share the workbook, but the codes are completely same as in my workbook.

Comment: Your code should work! I wanted to see what's wrong with your workbook. But no problem with me...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to be posting as an answer, not enough rep.

Shouldn't `Cancel=True` be inside the if statement? You are locking it up regardless of entry being numeric or not as is.

**Edit**:
Actually upon further testing still not working proper. However, change event works better and you can get instant feedback for any non numerics.

Updated code would look like this, control names differ. I am used to working with .Text, same thing as .Value. Also, since I am not sure what you would do with an empty string, assumed it to be yellow background as well.

One concern would be, can you allow comma or period in there? Depending on locale settings, a decimal would also be considered a numeric.

```
Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()

    Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub cmdEnter_Click()
    
    If TextBox1.BackColor = rgbYellow Then Exit Sub
    test4.Range("A1").Value = TextBox1.Text

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    If Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Or TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = rgbYellow
    Else
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = rgbWhite
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Edit 2**: I use this piece of code to check for only numbers (assuming number Ascii codes are standard). Maybe it can help.

```
Public Function isnumber(ByVal strValue As Variant) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    isnumber = True
    If Not strValue = "" Then
        For i = 1 To Len(CStr(strValue))
            If Asc(Mid(strValue, i, 1)) > 57 Or Asc(Mid(strValue, i, 1)) < 48 Then
                isnumber = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        isnumber = False
    End If
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear
    
End Function
```

**Edit 3**: I have revised the TextBox1_Change event code so all invalid characters are stripped right away. However, in this state if you copy paste a serial no with a non-allowed char, it will strip them leaving only the numbers. Not sure if it is acceptable.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    If Not isnumber(TextBox1.Text) Or TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.BackColor = rgbYellow
            
        Dim i As Long
        Dim strValue As String
        
        strValue = ""
        
        If Not TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            For i = 1 To Len(CStr(TextBox1.Text))
                If Not (Asc(Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)) > 57 Or Asc(Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)) < 48) Then
                    strValue = strValue & Mid(TextBox1.Text, i, 1)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
        
        TextBox1.Text = strValue
        
    Else
        If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
            TextBox1.BackColor = rgbWhite
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Many Thanks, Mr. Gokhan Aycan.  No comma or period is allowed in the textbox, i just have a preli. try, and it seems work.  I need some time to verify it really work or not...and will let you know...

Comment: Thanks again.  I have tried your first edition, one disadvantage is letter can still be entered (yes, its backcolor is shown in yellow in case the input is letter, however this is not my original idea).  I am going to include your second edition, but i would like to clarify something at first, that is the public function name is  Isnumber, but it seems i cannot find this keyword in your first edition, or there are something i get misunderstand....? Thanks.

Comment: isnumber is a function that I have written myself (might have gotten the idea from the net), it is like any other function. Instead of `IsNumeric (TextBox1.Text)` you would use `isnumber (TextBox1.Text)`. For the part where you can still enter other characters, you can  strip the invalid characters (anything other than numbers) from the text right away instead of coloring the background with yellow perhaps?

Comment: I include the edition 2 into the program, yes is better than using IsNumeric, however I can still enter the serial no with letter into the list, that is not i want.... (Yes, the combobox backcolor change to yellow when there is a letter.)

Comment: In the case of Edit 3, since we assign the stripped strValue back to the textbox, another unnecessary change event fires. This may be acceptable or not depending on your scenario. If unacceptable, you can use a userform scoped global boolean variable to bypass the change event's code to prevent the unnecessary computation.

Comment: This maybe a nature limitation of vba.....Anyway, Thanks a lot!